# Are there any similar words or phrases for「分かりました」

Tags: phrases

The only one I can come up with is 「そうなんですか！」 but even then the meaning and feeling is slightly different than "I understand/I got it".

Context:
So if my Japanese teacher teaches me something useful, I'd say something like "Ah! I get it now.", but I think using 「分かりました」 all the time makes me sound like a soldier.

Comment: ちょっとコンテクストが欲しいかも・・

Comment: So if my Japanese teacher teaches me something useful, I'd say something like "Ah! I get it now." right, but I think using「分かりました」all the time makes me sound like a soldier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could say...

「なるほど！」
「あぁ、そうなんですね！」
「あぁ、そうか、わかりました！」
「あぁ、そういうことなんですね！」(← This is like "Oh, that makes sense!")

---

I think it would be alright to repeat わかりました though... Maybe you could use some fillers, like 「あっ、そうか、わかりました（、ありがとうございます）！」...「あぁ、なるほど！わかりました！」...「あぁ、そうなんですね！わかりました。」... then you wouldn't sound so repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

そうなんですか！ means something like : "is that so!?"

You could use the following 4. Which are used quite frequently.

> 承知{しょうち}しました
>   了解{りょうかい}しました
>   了承{りょうしょう}しました
>   かしこまりました

They all have about the same meaning, but are used in different occasion mostly depending on required level of politeness.